# Jquery simplifying multiple if statements related to multiple ids with similar characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to simplify a list of functions down to a single function. Basically I have 6 divs, each with the id #slide_ where the underscore is a number from 1-6 (#slide1, #slide2, etc).

My functions are something like this:

```
if ($("#slide1").hasClass('active')) {});
```

There is one of these if statements for each of the #slide_ ids. What is the best way to simplify this so I have have a single function instead of 6 different if statements?

Comment: Your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBPug/35/) has several mistakes. Take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/mBPug/40/)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("[id^='slide']").each(...)
```

Note though that this will match all elements with an ID that begins with "slide". The better solution is to assign a class to the elements you want to target, and select the class instead.

Comment: What is the point if jQuery is only going to test the first element every time? This isn't going to work.

Comment: Your code is the same as `$("#slide1").hasClass("active");`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - No, my code would match `$("#slide2")`, `$("#slide3")`, etc as well. Yours wouldn't.

Comment: Oh I see where we're not on the same page. Yes of course, however I'm assuming that he's looping already. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh wait I double-checked the documentation and it seems like `hasClass` can actually test every element in the selection and will return true if at least one has the class (which surprised me). You were right.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - it will return true if at least one has the class, however it appears he wants to check each slide individually, not necessarily "are any of them active". some clarity on the requirements would influence the code.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 it still wouldn't be the correct answer, because hasClass returns `boolean` and can't be used as iterating through fitted elements

Comment: If that is the case why don't you just do `$("[id^=slide] .active")`?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yes, the answer has to be `$("[id^='slide'].active").each(function() {});`

Comment: @Regent - Yea that's the simplest and fastest way I can think of.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 well, I still hope that someone will edit his answer to this version, so that I can vote it up :)

Comment: @Regent - simplest yes, fastest no. `.each()` is horrifically slow compared to a standard `for` loop. also, the reinstantiation of `$(this)` within each rather than leveraging the cached slides would slow things down further.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea - When there's only 6 slides at max the difference in speed is insignificant.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea you are correct, but you can still simplify your answer by `var $slides = $("[id^='slide'].active")` and omitting `if` - won't it be more simple and maybe even faster?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - "it works good enough" is a terrible way to code, you should be using best practices. @Regent - agree with the former (CSS selectors for this are now slightly faster, 2.91% on jsPerf), however `.each()` is multiples of more than 100x slower so yes ... the `if` statement would still be much faster.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I mean if you will still use loop `for(var i = $slides.length; i--;)` but `var $slides = $("[id^='slide'].active")` (and omitting `if)` - it shouldn't work longer, but will look simpler, don't it?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea `.each` might not be the fastest, but it isn't the worst either. I wouldn't over-optimize every single statement in my code. Since this loop will always have a fixed length, unless it runs really slow on certain devices, I wouldn't optimize it down to every single detail. If everything has to be optimized before going to production, we would have to use something like Google Closure Compiler for every program we wrote.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I was hoping simplifying my code would solve my issue, but it didn't. I was using it here http://jsfiddle.net/mBPug/35/... Willing to tip if we solve this issue. I have tried everything.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - over-extrapolating in your justification. there is excessive work effort to ensure that you are doing it as fast as possible (laborious and costly), and there is outright avoidance and ignorance of better methods because you'd rather stick to what you already know than learn anything (lazy and complacent). its the difference between optimizing and over-optimizing.

Answer (score 3):

Loop that sucker up! First, apply a class (I use `.slide` for example purposes):

```
var $slides = $('.slide');
```

Or (if you can't mod the HTML) you can use the "starts with" selector that @j08691 references:

```
var $slides = $('[id^="slide"]');
```

Then apply a `for` loop on that collection:

```
for(var i = $slides.length; i--;){
    if($slides.eq(i).hasClass('active')){
        // do your magic
    }
}
```

Or you can take it even farther and if you are doing something to the same object, just filter the record set:

```
$slides.filter(function(){
    return $(this).hasClass('active');
}).applyMethod();
```

If you are modifying objects other than the slides then use the loop, else if you are modifying the slides themselves use the filter. Either way, it should work.